# ensimeConfig creates directories java and scala-2.11, which I don't need

Tags: scala, sbt, ensime

When I run `ensimeConfig`, it creates directories such as

```
src/main/java
src/main/scala-2.11
```

which I don't need, since I have my sources always inside

```
src/main/scala
```

How can I avoid such behaviour?

NOTE: This is the version I'm using:
`addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "sbt-ensime" % "1.12.4")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution. Create `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt` like this:

```
import org.ensime.EnsimeKeys._

ensimeIgnoreMissingDirectories := true
```

Comment: it informs you about this as it creates the directories

Comment: @fommil: yes. it does. I need glasses. :-)

Comment: For anyone it may interest, see my script which automagically installs Scala, SBT and ENSIME into your environment:
https://github.com/frgomes/debian-scripts/blob/master/install-scala.sh

Comment: cool, thanks, but your `install_scala` is redundant (sbt does this already, with ensime making it all available) and you could benefit from adding a jenv installation too.

Comment: @fommil: I do not use jenv. I use virtualenv, which attends all my needs pretty well. Another project of mine http://github.com/frgomes/debian-bin automagically sets the virtual environment for me. Maybe in future I merge the two projects into one, since in fact, they work in tandem.